# Check another session's IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS setting

Tags: sql-server, metadata

In SQL Server, you can find `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` value for own session via `@@OPTIONS`.

How to find the `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` value for another session?

This can definitely be done, because SQL Server Profiler shows it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in way to achieve this.

Vote for a product improvement at [Easier identification of Implicit Transactions](http://web.archive.org/web/20200414052354/https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33166555-easier-identification-of-implicit-transactions) (archive link until Microsoft migrates User Voice content)

In the meantime, the workarounds are:

1. Run a server-side trace (deprecated) including the [ExistingConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/existingconnection-event-class) event class
2. Use the `existing_connection` [extended event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events).

Answer (score 0):

The `name` column of the DMV `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` contains this info. Below is an example.

```
+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| transaction_id | name                      | transaction_begin_time  | transaction_type | transaction_uow | transaction_state | transaction_status | transaction_status2 | dtc_state | dtc_status | dtc_isolation_level | filestream_transaction_id |
+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|    28320660670 | LobStorageProviderSession | 2023-10-15 14:17:01.090 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|    28472577580 | implicit_transaction      | 2023-10-15 20:21:01.773 |                1 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                 258 |         0 |          0 |                  -1 | NULL                      |
|    28462491383 | user_transaction          | 2023-10-15 19:56:40.923 |                1 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                 258 |         0 |          0 |                  -1 | NULL                      |
|          16757 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|          16762 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|          16764 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|          16766 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|          16771 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|          16776 | worktable                 | 2023-09-25 23:36:51.540 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|    28472578838 | implicit_transaction      | 2023-10-15 20:21:02.017 |                1 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                 258 |         0 |          0 |                 256 | NULL                      |
|    28472578847 | implicit_transaction      | 2023-10-15 20:21:02.017 |                1 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                 258 |         0 |          0 |                 256 | NULL                      |
|    28471459239 | Backup/Restore            | 2023-10-15 20:18:24.440 |                2 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                   0 |         0 |          0 |                   0 | NULL                      |
|    28472205018 | user_transaction          | 2023-10-15 20:20:07.997 |                1 | NULL            |                 2 |                  0 |                 258 |         0 |          0 |                  -1 | NULL                      |
+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: This is interesting, but the description in the instructions is somewhat vague. And in my case, this field in very rare cases contains the isolation level.